# (Ordered) field's multiplicative identity added to itself $n$ times isn't its additive inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, arithmetic, inverse

Let $(K,+,*)$ be a field. Let $1_K$ be the field's multiplicative identity. Let $(-1_K)$ be its additive inverse. Let $0_K$ be the field's additive identity.

I'm trying to prove that for every $n>0_{\mathbb{N}}$, $f=\underbrace{1_K+...+1_K}_{n\, times\,+}$ isn't equal to $0_K$.

Since $+:K{\times}K{\rightarrow}K$, I know that I can write $f$ as $1_K+k$.  I can also prove that for any two field elements $x$ and $y$, $x+y=0{\implies}x+y+(-x)=0+(-x){\implies}y=-x$ and so $f=0$ only iff $k=(-1_K)$.

And here we arrive at my original question: how to show that $k$ can't be equal to $(-1_K)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true. Consider $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.  This is a finite field, and $1+1+1=0$.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Integers (mod 3).

Comment: And what about ordered fields? Is the theorem true at least for them?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is true, since then $x+1>x$ for any $x$.

Comment: Why does $x<x+1$? I just tried to prove it, but couldn't find any immediately obvious way and didn't find the proof after a search on the Internet.

Comment: are you assuming $1>0$?

Comment: I'm assuming only the ordered field axioms, I don't know if this is their consequence. If it isn't, I'm not. I can see how this would prove $x<x+1$ though.

Comment: $1>0$ implies $x+1>x+0$.

Comment: $1>0$ is a consequence of the ordered field axioms btw.

Comment: In what way? I suppose that it's somehow related to ${\forall}x:0<x{\implies}0<x*1$, but I don't know where to go further.

Comment: Consequence of $x^2\ge 0$ for all $x$.